# How to add new line and display the innerHTML in the row if column exist in ag-grid angular

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I am newbie to the ag grid,  using community version with angular 14, displayed the table data of employees , now i a trying i add a new line to the row if particular comments column exists, dug all over the internet, don't find any solution. Please assist, thanks in advance.

```
------------------------------
| Column 1 | Column 2        |
------------------------------
| Value 1  | Value 2         | 
|    comments : Good         |
------------------------------
| Value 3  | Value 4         |
------------------------------
| Value 5  | Value 6         |
|    comments : Working      |
------------------------------
```

Comment: Maybe this may be useful: https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/column-spanning/

Comment: @DieterRehbein  Thank you for the reply, but i want do the colspan, would like to display as a new row